# Laravel Socialite: Missing required parameter: redirect_uri

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I am using Laravel 5.3 with Socialite.

I am getting 400 Bad Request error with message:

```
Missing required parameter: redirect_uri
```

The URL it generates is:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=openid+profile+email&response_type=code&state=RYPmT1B93CaUdi44Z7iwfmRPx3hIy7an7yxAVY9l
```

Details below:

**service.php**

```
'google' => [
        'client_id' => '1234455-u3ifk8tr1qs41487fmevg2h2s1v6ubue.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        'client_secret' => 'DxSOS0p1xKNuPger3IS_E4-i',
        'redirect' => 'http://localhost:8000/google/callback',
    ],
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/{provider}/redirect', 'Auth\RegisterController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('/{provider}/callback', 'Auth\RegisterController@handleProviderCallback');
```

**Authorized URI settings in Google Console**

```
http://localhost:8000/google/callback
```

**Controller**

```
public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
    {
        try {
            $social_user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return redirect('/');
        }
}
```

Comment: Might want to hide your ID and Secret from public view...

Comment: @AndyHolmes Don't worry, already altered :)

Comment: Well, the error seems obvious. You need to add the redirect_uri parameter to the request. ?redirect_uri=/some/uri.

Answer (score 1):

Just double check your service.php file, env file and api setting in google console

Example (no env in redirect):

```
'google' => [
        'client_id' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'redirect' => 'http://localhost:8000/api/login/google/callback'
],
```